# List YouTube videos titles and url from an extracted HTML

Tags: python, html, video, youtube

I'm making a simple script with Python 3.5, it asks a title (e.g. a song), it goes on youtube.com/results?search_query=my+title and extracts the html code.

That's what I did, but now i'm facing a problem: I want my script to list the videos propositions title and register the corresponding link, so e.g it gives me a list like this

> Search: "eazy e"
>
> 1. Eazy E - Real muthaf***** G's
> 2. Eazy E - Boys In Da Hood etc..
>
> Insert the number of the video:

The problem here is that I have a HUGE load of html code and I don't know how to list what I want to have...

I used urlib.request.urlopen('http://youtube.com/results?search_query='+url_search_content) to extract the html code

Please help

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Comment: Looks like the links are stored in `href` right before `class= "yt-uix-sessionlink yt-uix-tile-link yt-ui-ellipsis yt-ui-ellipsis-2       spf-link "` You can use BeautifulSoup to find and extract the URLS

Comment: @PrestonM Python 3.5

Comment: @GriffinBabe keep in mind, most users here put in about as much effort into solving your question as the poster has formulating it. we're not here to do your work for you, we're here to help you do yours

Comment: @RafaelMartins Thank you ! It helps me a lot :)

Comment: @RafaelMartins what do you mean? If you're saying that my problem is badly formulated I'm sorry then, I don't have a good english

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built in htmlparser library in python to extract the tags that contain the titles of the videos that you want. This library will be give you multiple ways to parse through tags as well as provide you with a clearer readable output.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html

Keep in mind though that youtube search results are often multiple pages of content, and your html results will only be for one of these pages.

Comment: Thank you! Yes I know that :)